# Sending an object via sockets java

Tags: java, sockets

How can I send objects of a class via sockets? As of now I'm only able to send the class members one by one via sockets and I want to send the object as a whole. Explaining with a simple example would be great. Thanks.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the `java.io.Serializable` interface for the objects you want to transer.
Then `ObjectInputStream` or `ObjectOutputStream` to `readObject` or `writeObject` 
E.g.

```
   InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();   
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);   
   MyObject obj = (MyObject)ois.readObject();  
   //Now use the object

    Where:  
    class MyObject implements Serializable {  
      //variables
    }
```